# DocuSign multiple signatures

Tags: java, docusignapi

I am working on a project which needs multiple users of the application to sign a document with docusign.

I was working with the JAVA quickstart project and tried to retrieve a document after signing using the download document example (7th one on the page )in the quickstart.

The document was sent via the bulk signature example and I signed it through two of my e-mail accounts. I hardcoded the document id and the envelope id in the

code as the quickstart by default only lets you view a document created through example 2. The document does get downloaded but I cannot see the signatures on it.

Secondly, when I signed the document from the two accounts, I signed it from both in the same place to see how it will get handled.

Lastly I see the option to place the signature widget by the signer only in the bulk signature example, can this be enabled for any signature request ?(This may be there somewhere in
the documentation but i could not find it anywhere)

In general, there is very little clarity on how multiple signatures are handled in docusign (How the widget is placed, who can place them, how they are finally visible on the document when the document
is completled, and when signatures are being done in some order, then do the succeeeding signers see the signatures of the preceeding ones), will greatly appreicate any help on this.

Regards,

ANur

Answer (score 1):

Signatures are placed in documents using [Tabs](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/esign101/concepts/tabs/). In the Java Quickstart there are a few helper functions that add the tabs to the documents. You can find those functions in [this file](https://github.com/docusign/code-examples-java/blob/master/src/main/java/com/docusign/controller/eSignature/examples/EnvelopeHelpers.java#L173). When you're dealing with multiple signers you need to make sure that the tabs are associated with the correct recipients. If you download the document using example 7 before the document has been signed it won't have the signature fields on it but after it has been signed you should see the signatures there. I don't think DocuSign will prevent the two signers from placing their signatures in the same location but you can prevent that by specifying the locations of the SignHere tabs so that they do not overlap.

For more on placing tabs in documents you can check out [this blog post](https://www.docusign.com/blog/developers/tabs-deep-dive-placing-tabs-documents).

Comment: Thanks for the  response. I cannot see the signatures even after signing actually. Also more importantly when I tried to sign as e second signer after signing as d first signer I could not see the first signers signature. What I would really like to do is this : For a document or a set of documents for signing, I would like to give the signer control on where to sign. Also when they sign they should be able to see the previous signatures so that they do not overlap. Lastly when I download the signed documents I should be able to see all signatures. I am using the pages app on Mac to view pdf

Comment: **Update, the signatures are not visible even after viewing with Acrobat reader

Comment: If you set the routing order on the signers the second signer should be able to see the first signer's signature. The second signer will only receive an email notification once the first signer has signed. To set the routing order you can use the routingOrder parameter for each recipient. https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/reference/envelopes/enveloperecipients/#core-recipient-parameters